# Swap register key from @ to another more accessible key

Tags: key-bindings, macro, register

I used many macros assigned to registers, for instance I have this line in my `.vimrc`:

```
let @p='^[O</p>^[0jj'
```

I just type `@p` and it closes the tag, very convenient.

**PROBLEM**: On my new keyboard `@` (at-mark) is too far away.
**QUESTION**: Can I change it to another key? `;` would be convenient.

Comment: May want to consider a different key than `;` as `;` is rather useful. `;` repeats the last `t`/`f`. See `:h ;`

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
:noremap ; @
:noremap @ ;
```

The first line maps the `;` key to the register feature.

The second line maps the `@` key to whatever feature was assigned to the `;` key, just in case you need it. It is optional.

`noremap` creates a **no**n-**re**cursive **map**ping.

*Thanks to Carpetsmoker for the tip!*

Answer (score 2):

On azerty keyboards `@` is on the same key as `à` but it is less convenient to use since you have to press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> to get it. As `à` is not really useful in Vim I used `langmap` to switch the key only in normal mode (see [`:h 'langmap'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27langmap%27)).

With this in my `.vimrc`:

```
set langmap+=à@
```

I can use <kbd>àp</kbd> to execute the macro in the register `p`. And the insert mode still works the same.